# Category of small sets

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

According to Wikipedia

```
Ordinary categories are categories enriched over (Set, ×, {•})
```

And

```
Locally small categories are categories enriched over the category of small sets with Cartesian product
```

I struggle to make sense out of this category $\mathrm{SmallSets}$, as well as I struggle to see how a category which is not locally small can be enriched over sets

Comment: Fwiw: [Small and large categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)#Small_and_large_categories), [Small set (category theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_set_(category_theory)).

Comment: It's just a minor pedantic point. If $\textbf{Set}$ means the category of small sets obviously only locally small categories can be enriched over $\textbf{Set}$.

Comment: But is it possible to consider category of large sets, and then enrich large categories over it?

Comment: And how can one define such a category?